Quasar Carousel thumbnails scrollbar does not update when using navigation arrows
When using navigation arrows or the previous() and next() methods the current thumbnail is shown with a thick border if visible on the screen. If I have more thumbnails than what can be displayed, a scrollbar appears which can be used to see the hidden thumbnails. On the other hand if I move to a thumbnail which is outside the visible ones using navigation arrows or previous() next() methods, the thumbnail is not scrolled into visibility and the scrollbar stays without updating.
Select the rightmost visible thumbnail when the scrollbar is at left and then use the right navigation arrow or next() to bring the next image into visibility. The thumbnails do not scroll to show the next thumbnail nor does the scrollbar update its slider accordingly.
Modified original example at
https://codepen.io/devapen/pen/raBNgLm
Operating System - Windows_NT(10.0.19045) - win32/x64
NodeJs - 20.10.0

Global packages
  NPM - 10.2.3
  yarn - Not installed
  @quasar/cli - 2.3.0
  @quasar/icongenie - Not installed
  cordova - You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
11.0.0

Important local packages
  quasar - 2.14.3 -- Build high-performance VueJS user interfaces (SPA, PWA, SSR, Mobile and Desktop) in record time
  @quasar/app-vite - 1.7.3 -- Quasar Framework App CLI with Vite
  @quasar/extras - 1.16.9 -- Quasar Framework fonts, icons and animations
  eslint-plugin-quasar - Not installed
  vue - 3.5.12 -- The progressive JavaScript framework for building modern web UI.
  vue-router - 4.2.5
  pinia - 2.2.6 -- Intuitive, type safe and flexible Store for Vue
  vuex - Not installed
  vite - 2.9.17 -- Native-ESM powered web dev build tool
  eslint - 8.56.0 -- An AST-based pattern checker for JavaScript.
  electron - Not installed
  electron-packager - Not installed
  electron-builder - Not installed
  register-service-worker - 1.7.2 -- Script for registering service worker, with hooks
  @capacitor/core - 5.7.8 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/cli - 5.7.8 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/android - 5.7.8 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/ios - 5.7.8 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web


it needs to be shown with code how to reproduce this.  Please add enough code for a minimal reproduction to the question.

Example added on codepen
